# CentOS: install software using text UI

Tags: centos, centos-6

I've downloaded CentOS-6.6-i386-minimal.iso (because the DVD images are too large for my narrow internet access. How can I install software (e.g. Gnome desktop) now from the console? Is there something like Yast available where I can select what package to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Gnome, you'll use the following commands:

```
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

You can also install the following optional GUI packages.

```
yum -y groupinstall "Graphical Administration Tools"

yum -y groupinstall "Internet Browser"

yum -y groupinstall "General Purpose Desktop"

yum -y groupinstall "Office Suite and Productivity"

yum -y groupinstall "Graphics Creation Tools"
```

All this is from here: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_AddGNOMEToCentOSMinimalInstall.shtml

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to dump the minimal system, because it had no network access. Now I'm using the netinstall which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS' package manager is [YUM](http://yum.baseurl.org/). There's a pretty good [user guide](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html) on the CentOS site, but the quick and dirty for installing software with YUM is:

```
yum install <package-name>
```

Unless you're already running as root you'll need to sudo or su as appropriate.